# error validating url from youtube in bash

Tags: bash, regex, bash-scripting

I have a following code:

```
read -p ":" URL
regex='^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com)\/.+$'

    if [[ "$URL" =~ $regex ]]; then
        echo "not valid url "
        exit
    fi
echo 'Init fnction'
Init FUnction
```

I enter the url: https://www.asdasd.com/watch?v=nD8WpYD_P94

but the script does not come out valid as good:
output:

```
+ regex='^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com)\/.+$'
+ [[ https://www.asdasd.com/watch?v=nD8WpYD_P94 =~ ^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com)\/.+$ ]]
+ sleep 0.5
+ echo 'Init function...'
Init function...
```

I don't understand, what is the correct way to validate a url on youtube?

Comment: `www\.youtube\.com` doesn't match `www.asdasd.com` , review your regex.

Comment: For this reason, it does not match, you should exit the script and not continue as you do.

Comment: Is `if matches; then echo "not valid"; …` a sane logic? Shouldn't it be `valid`?

Comment: URL_wrong: https://www.asdasd.com/watch?v=nD8WpYD_P94                                       URL_correct: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nD8WpYD_P94                               if URL_Wrong then exit

Comment: What does your script do for the two URLs? If it behaves exactly opposite from what you expect, then the logic you implemented is opposite from what you want. This is my point from the beginning.

Comment: If my assumption is right then please answer this: was your question asked because of a typo or a brain fart? Or did you (do you) think `=~` is *negated* `=`? If the former then the question may be deleted. If the latter then the question deserves a proper answer.

Comment: Let's see, I want that when a url that does not contain youtube is entered and the script is not validated, enter the if and exit the execution with exit 676 for example, how difficult is it ???

Comment: You're doing the opposite. Is this because of a typo or a brain fart? Or do you expect `=~` to work in the opposite way than it does? `=~` tests positive match against the regex. You assume `not valid` after a match. Why?

Comment: nootttttt , If I put = only, you will see that the two URLs do not enter the if, check it yourself

Comment: So you do think `=~` is negated `=`. This I needed to know. Thank you. Expect an answer soon.

Comment: I know, but the two urls work, I edit the code

Comment: In fact, the ~ the original code did not have it

Comment: Please do not substantially change the question while I'm composing an answer that solves your original problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132222/discussion-between-kamil-maciorowski-and-ortiga).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `[[ ]]` `=~` is not a negated `=`.

`=~` is an operator that allows you to match against a regular expression, while `=` has nothing to do with regular expressions. See [Conditional Constructs in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs), `[[` with its `=~` is described there. The most important fragment:

> An additional binary operator, `=~`, is available, with the same precedence as `==` and `!=`. When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression and matched accordingly […].

The test succeeds iff the regex matches. The flow of your script (`echo "not valid"` upon a match) makes me believe you think it's the other way around. You need to negate the test.

To negate your test, place `!` before the `[[`:

```
if ! [[ "$URL" =~ $regex ]]; then
```

Alternatively you can negate the expression inside the `[[ ]]`:

```
if [[ ! "$URL" =~ $regex ]]; then
```

Additionally please read [*Understanding `IFS= read -r line`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618) and adjust your `read` command maybe.

Comment: not works, the regex not valid

Comment: @ortiga The regex in question does not make my Bash 5.1.8 complain. Did you change the regex? If it was invalid, you would have got the error before posting the question. I read the fact your question asks about something else as confirmation that the regex worked for you at some point. If there is a problem with *another* (e.g. modified) regex then it's a separate problem; ask a separate question maybe. If there's a problem with identical regex then it's a mystery indeed. What is it then? There is no shebang in your script. Are you sure you are/keep using Bash?